# Type error has occured : Translation capacity exceeded

Tags: alloy

When I run my example i have the following type error :

```
Translation capacity exceeded.
In this scope, universe contains 21 atoms
and relations of arity 8 cannot be represented.
Visit http://alloy.mit.edu/ for advice on refactoring.
```

Is there any documentation how to solve it, I didn't found anything in the book.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the explanation in Section 5 in this paper

http://people.csail.mit.edu/aleks/website/papers/icse11-squander.pdf

Here is a quote from it

> To represent a relation *r* of arity *k*, Kodkod allocates a matrix of
>   size *n<sup>k</sup>*, where *n* is the number of atoms in the universe. For
>   performance reasons, Kodkod uses a single sequential array indexed by
>   a Java integer, and so the size of the matrix is limited to the
>   largest integer values in Java (Integer.MAX_VALUE).

In your case, 21<sup>8</sup> (37822859361) is greater than Integer.MAX_VALUE (2<sup>31</sup>-1 = 2147483647).

Comment: But I have no relation of arity 8 in my model.

Comment: Can you post your model?

Comment: The model is really big but I will post a slightly equivalent one

Comment: A recent post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22886819/refactoring-alloy-models) explains how such a "phantom" relation is sometimes created from a quantifier (in your case that quantifier has 8 variables, thus relation of arity 8)