# Alloy analyzer performance

Tags: alloy

I wrote a complex model in Alloy which contains 100 signatures and each signature has some relations based on the abstract signature. The problem occurs when I try solving the model. After about two hours, the analyzer returns a message saying the "solver run out of the memory, reduce the scope or increase the memory or simplify the model". The scope was already reduced to *1*. Also, the memory was increased to the maximum limit. I did this experiment in two machines (my laptop with *8GB* memory and my desktop with *4GB*) and I still get the same message.

Has any one faces this kind of problem? Is Alloy able to handle such a complex model?

Regards

Comment: Nice question.  In performance questions, however, the devil is in the details.  You may need to provide extracts from your model, or to create a *minimal* complete working example, for anyone to have a chance of helping you.  In the meantime:  try all the different SAT solvers shipped with Alloy (Options / SAT Solver); the [FAQ](http://alloy.mit.edu/alloy/faq.html#9) suggests Berkmin for large problems.  And be aware that sometimes [reformulating a predicate can help in unexpected ways](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22886819/refactoring-alloy-models).

Comment: All excellent suggestions.  I would also make sure that if the problem you are modeling in Alloy has a partial instance, the model is written so that the partial instance is recognized by the Alloy Analyzer.