# Modeling an HTTP transition system in Alloy

Tags: http, transition, alloy, model-checking, transition-systems

I want to model an HTTP interaction, i.e. a sequence of HTTPRequest/HTTPResponse, and I am trying to model this as a transition system.
I defined an ordering on a class State by using:

```
open util/ordering[State]
```

where a State is simply a set of Messages:

```
sig State { 
    msgSet: set Message
}
```

Each pair of (HTTPRequest->HTTPResponse) and (HTTPResponse->HTTPRequest) is represented as a rule in my transition system.
The rules are expressed in Alloy as predicates that let one move from one state to another.

E.g., this is a rule generating an HTTPResponse after a particular HTTPRequest is received:

```
pred rsp1 [s, s': State] {
    one msg: Request, msg':Response | (

       // Preconditions (previous Request)
    msg.method=get &&
    msg.address.url=sample_com &&

       // Postconditions (next Response)
    msg'.status=OK_200 &&

       // previous Request has to be in previous state
    msg in s.msgSet &&
       // Response generated is added to next state
    s'.msgSet = s.msgSet + msg' 
}
```

Unfortunately, the model created seems to be too complex: we have a dozen of rules (more complex than the one above but following the same pattern) and the execution is very slow.

**EDIT:** In particular, the CNF generation is extremely slow, while the solving takes a reasonable amount of time.

Do you have any suggestion on how to model a similar transition system?

Thank you very much!

Comment: In principle, you don't seem to be doing anything obviously wrong.  If you're making a sequence of states, though, doesn't your model entail that the server (or the entire system) is never in the same state twice?  That would seem to require a lot more states than you would otherwise need (as well as making readers say "Wait, isn't HTTP a stateless protocol?!"); you might get better performance if you allowed states to be reused.  Many things *can* affect performance; you've tried many different SAT solvers?

Comment: Thanks for your reply! This morning, I have tried several SAT solvers but I did not get better performances. In particular, it turns out that most of the analysis time concerns the generation of the CNF clauses. And you are right about the fact that we never get twice in the same state, but this should not be a problem in the case study that I am modeling. Any suggestion on how to improve the CNF generation phase?

Comment: Without more details, I am not in a position to suggest anything (and I doubt anyone else could be, either). You may need to provide a [minimum complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) illustrating the problem:  the shortest possible example that exhibits the performance issue.  The effort needed to produce such a minimal example may be significant, but it may also help you see a solution.

Comment: On the state re-use issue -- you may be right that your treatment of states doesn't invalidate the model.  The relevant point here however is that anything that requires a model to have more individuals can slow the analysis down.  Does allowing state reuse solve your performance issue?

Comment: I'm unable to replicate the problem; using the model you give in the pastebin, Alloy reports a failure to find a model in about 400 ms. (Many Stack Overflow moderators discourage the use of pastebin, by the way, as it renders the question less useful if the pasted material goes away.)  My very general advice would be:  start simpler, with an outline that has three or five signatures, and build up gradually; don't wait until you have 17 abstract signatures and 60+ concrete signatures before trying to instantiate the model.

Comment: Thanks for your interest in my issue! I worked at simplifying and commenting my model, but in such a way that its analysis still takes almost two hours (and in principle I would like to add further predicates). As I wrote above, the main idea is to write down a transition system modeling the behavior of a web application. The model consists in a sequence of State objects, and state transitions are driven by rules, each of which generates either a Request or a Response (based on the message contained in the previous State). Please find the code here: http://pastebin.com/TMBrdHGp

Comment: Sorry, actually the error in the pastebin model was my fault (now it is updated and correct). As you said, I started simpler and built up gradually: indeed if you enable only the first 5 rules (commenting the others in the honestAction predicate) and you run for 9, it takes a reasonable amount of time to execute. From rule 6 onward, it is not reasonable anymore.

Answer (score 1):

This is a model with an impressive level of detail; thank you for sharing it!

None of the various forms of `honestAction` by itself takes more than two or three minutes to find an instance (or in some cases to fail to find any instance), except for `rsp8`, which takes quite a while by itself (it ran for fifteen minutes or so before I stopped it).

So the long CNF preparation times you are observing are apparently caused by either (a) just predicate `rsp8` that's causing your time issues, or (b) the size of the disjunction in the `honestAction` predicate, or (c) both.

I suspect but have not proved that the time issue is caused by combinatorial explosion in the number of individuals required to populate a model and the number of constraints in the model.

My first instinct (it's not more than that) would be to cut back on the level of detail in the model, in particular the large number of singleton signatures which instantiate your abstract signatures.  These seem (I could be wrong) to be present either for bookkeeping purposes (so you can identify which rule licenses the transition from one state to another), or because the modeler doesn't trust Alloy to generate concrete instances of signatures like UserName, Password, Code, etc.

As the model now is, it looks as if you're doing a lot of work to define all the individuals involved in a particular example, instead of defining constraints and letting Alloy do the work of finding examples.  (Using Alloy to check the properties a particular concrete example can be useful, but there are other ways to do that.)

Since so many of the concrete signatures in the model are constrained to singleton cardinality, I don't actually know that defining them makes the task of finding models more complex; for all I know, it makes it simpler.  But my instinct is to think that it would be more useful to know (as well as possibly easier for Alloy to establish) that state transitions have a particular property in general, no matter what hosts, users, and URIs are involved, than to know that property `rsp1` applies in all the cases where the host is named `examplecom` and the address URI is `example_url_https` and whatnot.

I **conjecture** that reducing the number of individuals whose existence and properties are prescribed, and the constraints on which individuals can be involved in which state transitions, will reduce the CNF generation time.

If your long-term goal is to test long sequences of state transitions to test whether from a given starting point it's possible or impossible to arrive at a particular state (or kind of state), you may need to re-think the approach to enable shorter sequences of state transitions to do the job.

A **second conjecture** would involve less restructuring of the model.  For reasons I don't think I understand fully, sometimes quantification with `one` seems to hurt rather than help performance, as in [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22886819/refactoring-alloy-models), where explicitly quantifying some variables with `some` instead of `one` turned out to make a problem tractable instead of intractable.

That question involves quantification in a predicate, not in the model overall, and the quantification with `one` wasn't intended in the first place, so it may not be relevant here.  But we can test the effect of the `one` keyword on this model in a simple way:  I commented out everything in `honestAction` except `rsp8` and ran  the predicate `first != last` in a scope of 8, once with most of the occurrences of `one` commented out and once with those keywords intact.  With the `one` keywords commented out, the Analyser ran the problem in 24 seconds or so; with the `one` keywords in place, it ran for 500 seconds so far before I decided the point was made and terminated it.

So I'd try removing the keyword `one` from all of the signatures  with instance-specific individuals, leaving it only on get, post, OK_200, etc., and appData.  I would also try doing without the various subtypes of Key, SessionID, URL, Host, UserName, and Password, or at least constraining their cardinality in the `run` command.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed comments. We have investigated some of your suggestions and got some slightly better results. In particular, we replaced the Message Set in the signature State with a single Message (which is enough for our example) and this improved the performances significantly.