# Refactoring in Alloy

Tags: refactoring, alloy

I have an Alloy model with this relation in it:

sig myint {nextX: (myint -> myint -> myint) ->  myint, nextT: (myint -> myint -> myint) ->  myint}

and I get the following error message:

Translation capacity exceeded.
In this scope, universe contains 84 atoms
and relations of arity 5 cannot be represented.
Visit http://alloy.mit.edu/ for advice on refactoring.

I am wondering how the number of atoms is related to the supported relation arity, and how I could resolve this problem.

I would really appreciate your help.
Thanks a lot.
Fathiyeh

Answer (score 2):

This StackOverflow [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21387155/type-error-has-occured-translation-capacity-exceeded#answer-21460244) answers why the number of atoms is related to max relation arity.
(in your case, 84<sup>5</sup> (4182119424) is greater than `Integer.MAX_VALUE` (2147483647))

For some ideas on refactoring, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22886819/refactoring-alloy-models#answer-22887608).